# HTML Markup for Twitter Bootstrap Popovers

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to figure out what CSS classes to use to have [Bootstrap popovers](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers) like this:

[image]

The example above is similar to the first example in the bootstrap documentation.

How can I get a popover like the one above working on a `div` element using only markup, and without needing javascript calls and clicks?

Comment: Your English is great by the way! My only comment would be that `i` is always written as the capital `I` - `i` on its own is always wrong.

Comment: Please reopen this question. It has been edited to make the question clearer.

Comment: This is very valid, I have the same question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML that will render the popover looks something like this:

```
<div class="popover right popover-example">
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    <h3 class="popover-title">Popover right</h3>
    <div class="popover-content">
        <p>Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, by default, `.popup` is `display: none` so you may want to override; in this case, I added a class `popover-example` and will define the following additional CSS:

```
.popover.popover-example {
    display: block
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="popover right">
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    <h3 class="popover-title">Your title here</h3>
    <div class="popover-content">
        <p>Your content here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Replace the class 'right' with whatever way you want it to show up.